# Does any browser have issue with url-encoded UTF-8 in links

Tags: browser, urlencode

Our site just rolled a new version, and now pages have Unicode in the url. I see that Rails have properly url escaped these UTF-8 characters when rendering the anchor tags.

```
/regions/%E4%B8%AD%E5%BD%B0%E6%8A%95/
```

However I still see a lot of traffic with incorrectly encoded urls:

```
/regions/%A4%A4%B9%FC%A7%EB/
```

Apparently this is the same address, but encoded in something other than UTF-8, and then url escaped.

**Question**

I am wondering if there is any old browser, which will take correctly escaped url, unescape it to get UTF-8, encode it in some other encoding, and then url-escape it when requesting the server?

Otherwise I don't know how to explain these traffic.

Comment: That first link... If I decode it as UTF8, it shows as `/regions/中彰??/`. Is that even the correct URL? Cause, it seems like it's an invalid UTF8 text.

Comment: @Jay Yep it decodes correctly here (even the third character). East Asian language support is needed.

Comment: That second URL was encoded using *Big5 (Chinese Traditional)*. I can only guess the web browser is a custom built for Chinese Windows OS, but doesn't properly handle URLs. You could set up a web tracker that'll retrieve the web browser information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested in Internet Explorer 6 and 7. I also tested the "Always send URLs as UTF-8" option. None of the combination caused incorrect encoded request.

I am guessing this was by some web crawler which handles the decoding but not encoding.